# Can't process_transaction twice within a test

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, testing

I'm trying to write test functions in Rust for an Anchor program, and I want to check that a particular instruction can't be called twice.

Hence, I'm trying to do `process_transaction` twice. But the logs seem to say that only the first one goes through, and the second one doesn't really do anything but also returns an `Ok()` value on `await-ing`.

Any help?

Comment: Any chance you can show us your code so we can have a better idea of how you did it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite an amusing issue that I ran into a few weeks ago while writing some new BPF tests for the Metaplex Candy Machine Program.

**The reason the second transaction is failing is almost certainly due to the fact that the signed and serialized transactions themselves are actually identical.**

Because the instructions, accounts, AND recent blockhash are all the same, the test validator will just toss out the second transaction because it appears to be a duplicate. This took me ages to debug, but once I figured this out the solution I went for is relatively simple: make sure the blockhash is updated when you send the second transaction. You can do this with a helper method like the following:

```
pub async fn update_blockhash(context: &mut ProgramTestContext) -> transport::Result<Hash> {
    let latest_blockhash = &context.banks_client.get_latest_blockhash().await?;
    let new_blockhash = context
        .banks_client
        .get_new_latest_blockhash(latest_blockhash)
        .await?;
    Ok(new_blockhash)
}
```

The code basically just requests a new blockhash based on the latest one it has available. There are probably ways to do this differently, but I just included this in all of our helper functions to ensure each transaction will be different. Here's a link to my code: [GitHub link](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/5c09f2b2b8bbc3aeb8baf059368142c75db98f14/candy-machine/program/tests/core/helpers.rs#L18).

It's from an older branch that I'm in the process of updating, so this code isn't live anywhere yet.

Edit: As mentioned by @sayantank, the `warp_to_slot` function should work too! It also doesn't rely on waiting for the slot to progress, so it may speed things up a bit. I don't have any code examples for this though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sammy, thank you so much for the answer! I had figured out a while later as well that the blockhash was same as the first transaction. So, I tried `warp_to_slot` and that seemed to work as well. But I was hoping you could help me understand the relation between the `context.blockhash`, `clock.slot`, and `clock.unix_timestamp`? When I'm running a BPF test, does the clock/slot move as well with time?

Comment: I'm actually working on a program that depends on the `clock.unix_timestamp`, and I just noticed that `warp_to_slot` doesn't really change the `clock.unix_timestamp` but does change the `clock.slot`. How does that make sense? I was under the impression that the `unix_timestamp` would change with the `slot`.

Comment: I'd imagine it should change based on POH? Not entirely sure what's going on if that isn't the case :(. That `warp_to_slot` method looks super handy, though! I thought I tried it while debugging this originally, but I may have been doing something wrong. I'll update my answer to reflect that method. Since its not async it should actually speed things up a bit.